# Laravel 4.1 eager loading polymorphic relation morphTo

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm having problem to try eager loading polymorphic relation in Laravel 4.1. Please take a look at this: [http://help.laravel.io/d1fb6a5b00975db6 … f037b002f4](http://help.laravel.io/d1fb6a5b00975db6f243b9ad4292cbf037b002f4)

Basically i tested non-polymorphic eager loading, and it works perfectly.

And if I tried this, it works:

```
Route::get('polytest', function ()
{
  $data = new \StdClass;
  $data->model = new \Picture;
  $posts = $data->model->find(1);
  $posts = $posts->authorable;
  //dd( DB::getQueryLog() );
  return $posts;
});
```

But this doesnt work:

```
Route::get('polytest', function ()
{
  $model = new \Picture;
  $posts = $model->with('authorable')
            ->orderBy('updated_at', 'desc')
            ->take(15)
            ->get();
  //dd( DB::getQueryLog() );
  return $posts;
});
```

PS: the related models and migrations are in the link above.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK it's not yet available in Laravel 4.1 master branch but a fix is on the way, in an already submitted pull request.

Still, if you need it up and running at the moment, you can make use of the PR anyway. Check it out:

https://github.com/laravel/framework/pull/3038

For details, follow the original discussion here:

https://github.com/laravel/laravel/issues/1681

**UPDATE:**

As @ChristianMichael reports in a comment below, **initial support for MorphTo eager loading** has been just **added** in version 4.1.23 of Laravel, big up!

Comment: Thank you @Gadoma for editing the title :D 
uhh.. just read that, so I guess i'll sit this one out first... see how it turns out :(

Comment: Hehe sure, sorry... still not familiar with this whole process... I thought it would be decided based on votes.

Comment: Update info: Taylor Otwell, creator of Laravel has just pushed initial support for MorphTo eager loading as in version 4.1.23 :)